# SQLite: order so that results with same starting letter would come first?

Tags: sql, sqlite

SQLite 3.7.11

Given I have these two records in a SQLITE table, with the field called `name`:
"**preview**"
"**view**"

If I run the query:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE "%" + $keyword + "%" ORDER BY name`

with $keyword set to "**vi**"

I would get the results in this order:
1) "preview"
2) "view"

Is there a way to order so that the names whose first letter is the same as the first letter of the keyword (in this example "v") would come first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it can be done less verbose, but this should work. I used `?` as a placeholder for your variable. The query as you posted it doesn't seem to be correct SQL.

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE name LIKE '%' || ? || '%'
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN SUBSTR(Name,1,1) = SUBSTR(?,1,1) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END), 
         name
```

Comment: Yours proved to be the best working solution. I had to add lower() in order to make it case insensitive.
`SELECT * FROM table
WHERE name LIKE '%' + $keyword + '%'
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN LOWER(SUBSTR(name,1,1)) = LOWER(SUBSTR($keyword,1,1)) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END), name`

Answer (score 2):

You can sort by the position of your keyword in the search string

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE name LIKE concat('%', '$keyword', '%')
ORDER BY POSITION('$keyword' IN name)
         name
```

Comment: I forgot some quotes. Does it work now? And if not - what error rises?

Comment: It says the "instr" function doesn't exist. In fact it was added only in december 2012 (version 3.7.15, http://www.sqlite.org/changes.html). I need to use it in an Android app, so unfortunately I can't use instr :-(

Comment: unfortunately the instr function isn't defined

Comment: @DanieleB: Try `position()`

Comment: And I believe concat() doesn't exist in SQLite either. Yes that is one primitive DBMS...